# Convert Now and Ten Minutes Ago to Different Timezone

Tags: php, timezone, timestamp

I would like to convert the timestamps from ten minutes ago and now to match the following format:

```
2018-09-23T04:47:07.237
```

Here are the timestamps I'd like to convert to match the above format:

```
$now = date('m/d/y g:i a');
$now = strtotime($now);
$ten_minutes_ago = strtotime('-10 minutes');
```

How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [date_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-format.php) function instead. You don't need to convert to UNIX timestamp using `strtotime` function. Instead use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) library

Check the following (**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/DJWMB51738)**):

```
$now = new DateTime(); // create a datetime object
$sub = new DateInterval("PT10M"); // Interval of 10 mins
$ten_minutes_ago = new DateTime();
$ten_minutes_ago->sub($sub); // subtract 10 minutes

// changed formats
$now_changed = date_format($now, DATE_ISO8601);
$ten_minutes_ago_changed = date_format($ten_minutes_ago, DATE_ISO8601); 

// print output
echo $now_changed; //2018-09-23T02:58:25-0400
echo $ten_minutes_ago_changed; // 2018-09-23T02:48:25-0400
```

**Details:**

- The date_format() function returns a date formatted according to the specified format.
- DATE_ISO8601 - ISO-8601 (example: 2013-04-12T15:52:01+0000)
- You can check for more formatting options [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_format.asp).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get this error: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, integer given in for $now_changed

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do what you are asking for.

If your data is in a string.  Here is the only line of code you need:

```
$date = date('m/d/y g:i a'); //Gets a date string.
echo substr(date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u', strtotime($date . ' -10 minutes')), 0, -3); // PHP < 7.0.0

//echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v', strtotime($date . ' -10 minutes')); //PHP > 7.0.0
```

This will produce:

Ex.

09/23/18 12:13 am

To

2018-09-23T00:03:00.000

One thing to note here.  The microseconds will always be zeros if your original input date is a string and in the format `m/d/y g:i a` that you have specified.  The reason being is that there is no millisecond information to be had from the date string.

If you create you input date as a dateTime object, the object will be able to keep track of the microseconds for you.